# How can i create a dynamic and reusable method to create a table with java and sqlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I want to have a method in java to create sqlite tables without knowing the number of columns

```
public static void createNewTable(String databaseName, String tableName, String typeOfAttribute1, String attribute1) {
        // SQLite connection string
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName;

        // static SQL statement for creating a new table
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ tableName + " (" + attribute1 + " " + typeOfAttribute1 + ");";


        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            // create a new table
            stmt.execute(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In this specific case i'm forced to create a table with only one column (attribute1). Is possible to have a more reusable approach and create a table without knowing the number of the columns?
I hope that everything is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder` and instead to pass list of columns i suggest to use a List which take an `Array[column_name, column_type]` like this :

```
public static void createNewTable(String databaseName, String tableName, List<String[]> columns) {
    // SQLite connection string
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName;
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (";
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(query);

    String prefix = "";

    for (String[] s : columns) {
        sql.append(prefix);
        prefix = ", ";
        sql.append(s[0]);
        sql.append(" ");
        sql.append(s[1]);
    }

    sql.append(");");
    System.out.println(sql);

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        // create a new table
        stmt.execute(sql.toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new String[]{"col1", "type1"});
    list.add(new String[]{"col2", "type2"});
    list.add(new String[]{"col3", "type3"});
    list.add(new String[]{"col4", "type4"});
    list.add(new String[]{"col5", "type5"});
    createNewTable("database_name", "table_name", list);
}
```

This will show you:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (col1 type1, col2 type2, col3 type3, col4 type4, col5 type5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use varargs, which is simply an array. Consider that each odd item is attribute name, each even item is attribute type:

```
public static void createNewTable(String databaseName, String tableName, String ...attributes) {
    if (attributes.length % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);

    // attributes[0] - 1st attribute name
    // attributes[1] - 1st attribute type
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length-1; i+=2) {
       // attributes[i] - i-st attribute name
       // attributes[i+1] - 1st attribute type
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I hope you can complete rest logic of this method by your self.